# Send props from parent to child and update them in child component (ReactJs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, react-props

I trying to make a pagination with a response from an API request made with ReactJs. I have one **Main.js** page that send props to child component which is **PageButtons.js**. Everything is passing well, I checked that by console logging this.props of the values I passed.
The thing is I need to update the state of props and I need that to get updated on **parent** component, which is Main.js. I'm using this to increment the value of limit and offset of the fetch API request, depending on the button I just clicked, but that does not happen... :(

This question as little bit more details, like the array of the fetch response ([Client-side pagination of API fetch only with ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51629778/client-side-pagination-of-api-fetch-only-with-reactjs?noredirect=1#comment90224612_51629778)).

I'll leave here Main.js code (no imports included):

```
export class Main extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    this.state = {
        token: {},
        isLoaded: false,
        models: [],
        offset: offset,
        limit: limit
    };
}

componentDidMount() {

    /* here is other two fetches that ask for a token */

    fetch(url + '/couch-model/', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'JWT ' + (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')).token)
        }
    }).then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
           return res.json();
       } else {
            throw Error(res.statusText);
       }
    }).then(json => {
    this.setState({
            models: json.results
        }, () => {});
   })
}


render() {

    const { isLoaded, models } = this.state;

    if (!isLoaded) {
        return (
            <div id="LoadText">
                Estamos a preparar o seu sofá!
            </div>
        )
    } else {

        return (
            <div>

               {models.map(model =>
                    <a href={"/sofa?id=" + model.id} key={model.id}>
                        <div className="Parcelas">
                            <img src={model.image} className="ParcImage" alt="sofa" />
                            <h1>Sofá {model.name}</h1>

                            <p className="Features">{model.brand.name}</p>

                            <button className="Botao">
                                <p className="MostraDepois">Ver Detalhes</p>
                                <span>+</span>
                            </button>
                            <img src="../../img/points.svg" className="Decoration" alt="points" />
                        </div>
                    </a>
                )}

                 <PageButtons limit={limit} offset={offset}/>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

}

And now PageButtons.js code:

```
export class PageButtons extends React.Component {

    ButtonOne = () => {
        let limit = 9;
        let offset = 0;
        this.setState({
            limit: limit,
            offset: offset
        });
    };

    ButtonTwo = () => {
        this.setState({
            limit: this.props.limit + 9,
            offset: this.props.offset + 9
        });
    };

    render() {

        console.log('props: ', this.props.limit + ', ' + this.props.offset);

        return (
            <div id="PageButtons">
                <button onClick={this.ButtonOne}>1</button>
                <button onClick={this.ButtonTwo}>2</button>
                <button>3</button>
                <button>></button>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below methods to Main.js

```
fetchRecords = (limit, offset) => {
    // fetch call code goes here and update your state of data here
}


handleFirstButton = (limit, offset) => {
    this.setState({limit : limit, offset: offset})
    this.fetchRecords(limit, offset)
}

handleSecondButton = (limit, offset) => {
    this.setState({limit: limit, offset : offset})
    this.fetchRecords(limit, offset)
}
```

Main.js render method changes :

```
<PageButtons 
    limit={limit} 
    offset={offset} 
    handleFirstButton={this.handleFirstButton} 
    handleSecondButton={this.handleSecondButton}/>
```

PageButtons.js changes.

```
ButtonOne = () => {
    let limit = 9;
    let offset = 0;
    this.props.handleFirstButton(limit, offset);
};

ButtonTwo = () => {
    let {limit, offset} = this.props;
    limit += 9;
    offset += 9;
    this.props.handleSecondButton(limit, offset);
};
```

Comment: `handleSecondButton' is not defined`@javed

Comment: just add this.handleSecondButton in you props declaration.

Comment: Nothing changed, still does not do the increment on props

Comment: can you just put console log in your render method of main.js and print limit and offset.

Comment: What I'm sorry, it updated on parent! But it doesn't rerender to make new request

Comment: you want to send new request whenever your limit and offset change. right?

Comment: Yes!! :) @javed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177199/discussion-between-javed-and-sofia-ribeiro).